# Memory Leak from C Socket Read Function

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am writing a small code to read ADS-B data from a Socket. The data is in following format

> MSG,6,1,1,4242D7,1,2017/12/25,12:04:05.695,2017/12/25,12:04:05.695,,,,,,,,6142,0,0,0,
>   MSG,4,1,1,80068D,1,2017/12/25,12:04:05.695,2017/12/25,12:04:05.695,,,183,268,,,-576,,,,,0
>   MSG,2,1,1,800B6F,1,2017/12/25,12:04:05.695,2017/12/25,12:04:05.695,,,7,165,28.53949,77.10886,,,,,,-1
>   MSG,5,1,1,4242D7,1,2017/12/25,12:04:05.695,2017/12/25,12:04:05.696,KAR2440
>   ,32025,,,,,,,0,,0

The strings are terminated by CRLF

I am presently using a readline function to read the data from the socket line by line

```
int readline(int fd, char ** out)
{
    /* Keep reading till header "MSG" is received
 * store it in buffer
 * keep reading till newline is encountered
 * exit function
 */
int buf_size = 512;
int bytesloaded = 0;
int ret;
char buf;
char * buffer = malloc(buf_size * sizeof(*buffer));
if (NULL == buffer)
{
    free(buffer);
    return -1;
}
//loop till header is received
while (1)
{
    bzero(buffer,buf_size);
    ret = read(fd, &buf, 1);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        free(buffer);
        return -1;
    }
    if (buf=='M')   //Got M; now wait for S
    {
        bytesloaded=0;
        buffer[bytesloaded] = buf;
        bytesloaded++;
        ret = read(fd, &buf, 1);
        if (ret < 1)
        {
            free(buffer);
            return -1;
        }
        if (buf=='S')   //Got S; now wait for G
        {
            buffer[bytesloaded] = buf;
            bytesloaded++;
            ret = read(fd, &buf, 1);
            if (ret < 1)
            {
                free(buffer);
                return -1;
            }
            if (buf=='G')   //Got G; now wait for CR-LF
            {
                buffer[bytesloaded] = buf;
                bytesloaded++;
                while(1)
                {
                    ret = read(fd, &buf, 1);
                    if (ret < 1)
                    {
                        free(buffer);
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if (buf=='\n')
                        break;
                    buffer[bytesloaded] = buf;
                    bytesloaded++;
                }
                buffer[bytesloaded] = '\0';
                *out = buffer; // complete line
        //free(buffer);
                return bytesloaded;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The above function is called from main using the following routine

> bytesread=readline(netfd, &netbuf);

The problem is the code footprint in the memory increases gradually indicating a memory leak. Valgrind also points to the readline function.
There is no memory leak if I uncomment the second last line (free(buffer)). But doing so gives me no data at output.
What am I missing here.

Comment: `What am I missing here.` Maybe a `free(...);` ?

Comment: The 2nd argument to function `int readline(int fd, char ** out)` should be a variable having space at the stack of the calling function i.e. the 2nd argument should be an array of 512 bytes. Also, in the code you are just pointing the pointer to locally allocated buffer `*out = buffer;` instead of this you should use `memcpy()` before freeing the `buffer` pointer.

Comment: A very nice tool I used to use when I had this kind of problems in C is [Dr. Memory](http://drmemory.org/). It will help you to analyze and solve the memory problem.

Comment: I did that by doing a malloc followed by free for the netbuf variable. It creates another set of leaks for me.. so I abandoned it. I will try memcpy() though.

Comment: `if (NULL == buffer)
{
    free(buffer);
    return -1;
}` This is not correct, if the pointer is null you cannot free it- Would give seg fault.  On your question, freeing of buffer should happen in the function where you call `bytesread=readline(netfd, &netbuf);`

Answer (score 1):

Your design indicates that the function `readline` allocates the memory required and returns a pointer to the calling function.

Using this design, the calling function MUST call `free` to avoid a memory leak.

I should point out that this design is often problematic and increases the chances for memory leaks.

A better design keeps memory management concerns together (the allocating function should free the memory. When this is impossible or impractical, the function name should clearly indicate the allocation and a destructor should be written (i.e., `line_alloc` and `line_free`), minimizing any confusion.